# NPS Certificate

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, pki, nps

I am changing a CA in the domain to a new one. The old CA will be deactivated.

I have an NPS server configured with the certificate of the old CA in "Network Policies -> Policy1 -> Constraint -> Authentication methods -> Microsoft: protected EAP".

By changing the certificate to the new one, the clients are no longer able to log in.

What could be the reason for this?
Do I have to do any additional configuration?